# nuget restore error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/index.json

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I run dotnet restore --interactive
It kept sending this error.
error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/index.json

But when I checked out my source confugration in Nuget management, it is https://api.nuget.org/api/v3/index.json and it can be opened through browser.

How can I change that url to the correct one?

I can see in .nuget/nuget/nuget.Config the packageSource settings has the line with key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"  protocalVersion="3".

But when I go restore nuget packages, it is still hitting https://www.nuget.org/api/v3/index.json. Why? Are there any other files I missed to change?

Comment: What happens if you use `dotnet restore --interactive -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`?

Comment: FYI, this issue happened to me while trying to do `dotnet restore` as part of a docker build. The root cause was that our company's Netskope tool was blocking requests that stemmed from containers, while not blocking requests from our local machines - we could run dotnet restore locally. The fix was to have our IT team add a rule to allow any requests to api.nuget.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer from here:

There is individual nuget.config existed in one of the project folder.
Reference to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

Comment: Yes, there can be many locations for `Nuget.config` and they are composable, which means that more specific versions of that file will override more general versions.

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation's article [NuGet Error NU1301](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1301):

- Restore could not be completed because the listed source is unavailable.
- Consult the error message for more details.
- You may need to inform the source owner as there might be issues that only they can address.
- Alternatively, you can try removing the source from the configuration retry again. The configured source may not be necessary for your build.

And the last sentence worked for me. No detailed error message was available, even with `dotnet restore --verbosity detailed`. The first source owner is not interested in support, and the current (my company) knows nothing more. So I disabled this source for this particular project with `dotnet nuget disable source <source_name>`, and yes, **the source was not necessary**.

Comment: he verbosity trick solved it for me. I was able to see the issue with the auth from the logs:
`[CredentialProvider]VstsCredentialProvider - Not running bearer token provider 'ADAL Windows Integrated Authentication'`

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do is install "NuGet targets and build tasks" from Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Worked for me.  I was using this computer as a build machine and needed this to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error while I wanted to use Add View for controller action. I Just connected the internet and then it installed some Nuget packages, then the error solved.